# openOrCreateDatabase fails

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

i have  problem with SQLLite database creation. I checked  db exists or not, close db connection. But i don't understand where i fail or openOrCreateDatabase fails.

```
...
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
...
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, version);
    currentContext = context;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),context.getString(R.string.cache_dirname));
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();     
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    DBPath=cacheDir.toString()+"/"; 
    createDatabase();
}

private void createDatabase() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();
    if (dbExists) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
                    // **fails here**           
        DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
        ...         
    }
}

private boolean checkDbExists() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("","database doesn't exists");
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

}

Error

```
Failed to open databse '/storage/emulated/0/My_test/dbtest'
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error code (14): Couldn't open database
```

Where is a fail?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
DBPath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getName()+"//data//com.your.package//databases//";

String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
```

Comment: Yes so works **DBPath="/data/data/"+ context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";**

Answer (score 1):

Its failng because you are opening the database in the default location, while creating directories and checking for the database in another place.

```
DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
```

"DBName" should be the fullpath to your database, or it will be created in the default location.  Here is code I use for opening a variable location database.

```
SQLiteDatabase m_db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(
        db_file.getAbsolutePath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null, null);
```

Combine your  path + "/" + dbname into a full path, or you can pass it a file that contains the proper path and use get absolute path.

Edit: I noticed you're actually opening the DB to check whether it exists.  This will demonstrate how check whether a DB exists, for a variable location:

```
 File db_file = new File(folder, dbName);
 boolean dbExists = db_file.exists();
```

Comment: DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBPath+DBName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);    :) but it doesn't help.

Comment: 1. test whether your .mkdirs succeeds, throw if it doesn't.
  2. check that you've actually allocated sd card space, the default is no space.  3. check that the error is occurring where you believe.  I do not see a full logcat, and don't see the "database does not exist" that you should be getting in checkDBexists.  Also, you shouldn't be trying to open a DB to check if it exists, see my code above for how to check it.